AddOpenApi - Adding Error Response types to all operations - .NET 9
I am upgrading a project from .NET 8 to .NET 9. The default support for Swagger UI and Swagger Docs has been removed and replaced with the AddOpenApi() and MapOpenApi().
In my Swagger json file, I would normally add common error response types to all endpoints using a custom IOperationProcessor implementation.
How do we go about upgrading from .NET 8 to .NET 9 and upgrading the open API documentation implementation?

So I just went through the process of upgrading to dotnet core 9, and switching from Swagger to Open API and Scalar UI.
I am documenting it here and the part of adding Error Response codes across all endpoints for anyone else who comes across a similar issue.
Step 1 : Is to update the dotnet version from dotnet 8 to dotnet 9
Step 2 : Uninstall Swashbuckle and any other related projects.
Step 3: Remove UseSwaggerUi() from the Program.cs
Step 4: Remove services.AddOpenApiDocument()...  from the ConfigureServices.cs
Step 5: Install Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi nuget package
Step 6: Intall Scalar.AspNetCore nuget package.
We will be using Scalar UI instead of Swagger UI
Step 7: Update the Program.cs file to include the MapOpenApi and MapScalarApiReference code
...
app.MapStaticAssets();

app.MapOpenApi();
app.MapScalarApiReference(options =>
{
    options
        .WithTitle("TITLE_HERE")
        .WithDownloadButton(true)
        .WithTheme(ScalarTheme.Purple)
        .WithDefaultHttpClient(ScalarTarget.JavaScript, ScalarClient.Axios);
});

app.UseRouting();
...

Step 8: Open ConfigureServices.cs and include the AddOpenApi() extension
{
...
// Customise default API behaviour
services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

// Add the Open API document generation services
services.AddOpenApi();
...
}

The above should be enough to get the Open API json file running.
So start the Web API and navigate to: https://localhost:PORT/openapi/v1.json
You should see the Open API json file.
and navigating to https://localhost:PORT/scalar/v1 should display the Scalar UI.
Adding default error responses to all operations.
So normally I define my API endpoints like below, as you can see I only define the success response and it's type.
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<GeofenceDto>), 200)]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<GeofenceDto>>> GetGeofences()
{
    return await Mediator.Send(new GetGeofencesQuery());
}

So when generating the Open API files, it only contains the success response types:

Which is okay if your API never returns an Error Response, I like to handle my errors using a custom exception handler like below.
public class CustomExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<HttpContext, Exception, Task>> _exceptionHandlers;

    public CustomExceptionHandler()
    {
        // Register known exception types and handlers.
        // Please note: add any new exceptions also the OpenApiGenerator.cs so they get included in the open api json document.
        _exceptionHandlers = new()
            {
                { typeof(ValidationException), HandleValidationException },
                { typeof(NotFoundException), HandleNotFoundException },
                { typeof(UnauthorizedAccessException), HandleUnauthorizedAccessException },
                { typeof(ForbiddenAccessException), HandleForbiddenAccessException },
            };
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var exceptionType = exception.GetType();

        if (_exceptionHandlers.ContainsKey(exceptionType))
        {
            await _exceptionHandlers[exceptionType].Invoke(httpContext, exception);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private async Task HandleValidationException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex)
    {
        var exception = (ValidationException)ex;

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ValidationProblemDetails(exception.Errors)
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
            Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"
        });
    }

    private async Task HandleNotFoundException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex)
    {
        var exception = (NotFoundException)ex;

        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails()
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound,
            Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
            Title = "The specified resource was not found.",
            Detail = exception.Message
        });
    }

    private async Task HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized,
            Title = "Unauthorized",
            Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235#section-3.1"
        });
    }

    private async Task HandleForbiddenAccessException(HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex)
    {
        httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;

        await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden,
            Title = "Forbidden",
            Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.3"
        });
    }
}

As you can see I have certain Exceptions thrown and handled with a specific Status Code.
One way to add these error responses is to add them to all the endpoints as error responses types.
but I want to do this using a common piece of code.
So to do this , Create a new file in your Web API project and give it a name of your chosing.
I named it OpenApiCustomGenerator, and paste in the following code, modify according to your error response types and codes:
public static class OpenApiCustomGenerator
{
    public static void AddOpenApiCustom(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddOpenApi(options =>
        {
            options.AddOperationTransformer((operation, context, ct) =>
            {
                // foreach exception in `CustomExceptionHandler.cs` we need to add it to possible return types of an operation
                AddResponse<ValidationException>(operation, StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest);
                AddResponse<UnauthorizedAccessException>(operation, StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized);
                AddResponse<NotFoundException>(operation, StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
                AddResponse<ForbiddenAccessException>(operation, StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });

            options.AddDocumentTransformer((doc, context, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                doc.Info.Title = "TITLE_HERE";
                doc.Info.Description = "API Description";

               // Add the scheme to the document's components
               doc.Components = doc.Components ?? new OpenApiComponents();

                // foreach exception in `CustomExceptionHandler.cs` we need a response schema type
                AddResponseSchema<ValidationException>(doc, typeof(ValidationProblemDetails));
                AddResponseSchema<UnauthorizedAccessException>(doc);
                AddResponseSchema<NotFoundException>(doc);
                AddResponseSchema<ForbiddenAccessException>(doc);

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            });
        });
    }

    // Helper method to add a response to an operation
    private static void AddResponse<T>(OpenApiOperation operation, int statusCode) where T : class
    {
        var responseType = typeof(T);
        var responseTypeName = responseType.Name;

        // Check if the response for the status code already exists
        if (operation.Responses.ContainsKey(statusCode.ToString()))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Create an OpenApiResponse and set the content to reference the exception schema
        operation.Responses[statusCode.ToString()] = new OpenApiResponse
        {
            Description = $"{responseTypeName} - {statusCode}",
            Content = new Dictionary<string, OpenApiMediaType>
            {
                ["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                {
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Reference = new OpenApiReference
                        {
                            Type = ReferenceType.Schema,
                            Id = responseTypeName
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // Helper method to add a response schema to the OpenAPI document
    private static void AddResponseSchema<T>(OpenApiDocument doc, Type? responseType = null)
    {
        var exceptionType = typeof(T);
        var responseTypeName = exceptionType.Name;

        // the default response type of errors / exceptions --> check: `CustomExceptionHandler.cs`
        responseType = responseType ?? typeof(ProblemDetails);

        // Define the schema for the exception type if it doesn't already exist
        if (doc.Components.Schemas.ContainsKey(responseTypeName))
        {
            return;
        }

        // Dynamically build the schema based on the properties of T
        var properties = responseType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .ToDictionary(
                prop => prop.Name,
                prop => new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = GetOpenApiType(prop.PropertyType),
                    Description = $"Property of type {prop.PropertyType.Name}"
                }
            );

        // Add the schema to the OpenAPI document components
        doc.Components.Schemas[responseTypeName] = new OpenApiSchema
        {
            Type = "object",
            Properties = properties
        };
    }

    // Helper method to map .NET types to OpenAPI types
    private static string GetOpenApiType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string) ? "string" :
               type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(long) ? "integer" :
               type == typeof(bool) ? "boolean" :
               type == typeof(float) || type == typeof(double) || type == typeof(decimal) ? "number" :
               "string"; // Fallback for complex types
    }

}

Update the ConfigureServices.cs to use your Custom Add Open API extension method.

Then restart the Application --> go to the Scalar or Swagger UI page you should be able to see the Error Responses with their Schema


This was a huge help. It's surprising ASP.NET doesn't already include (or provide an easy) way the default exception reponses (ProblemDetails).
